# adding a caption to squeezebox

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2, squeezebox

I'm using http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/ for mootools 1.2

There is an option to add a image or content, but I'd like to do something in between; or both. Essentially adding an image with some content underneath.

any insight how I could merge these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the image and content in a div and then use display the div a content using a squeezebox.
I have used the example @ http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/1-1/showcase/get-elements/  to show content and image using Squeeze box.

```
<a href="#demo-target-clone" rel="boxed">Show Image & Content</a> 

<div id="demo-target-clone">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2268/1624148602_c69850e3fc_t.jpg" alt="Sunny autumn river">
    <p>Image Content</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    SqueezeBox.assign($$('a[rel=boxed][href^=#]'), {
        size: {x: 200, y: 200}
    });

});
</script>
```

Check working example @  http://www.jsfiddle.net/AL93a/

Comment: adding a `<div style="visibility:hidden;">` around the other div helps. This means that I would need to create a container for every item. Seems like a brute force solution for captions, but might end up resorting to this, thanks.